# How should I aggregate multiple API requests?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, architecture, rest

We're building a web application that will make multiple API calls to the backend server (also designed by us). We're making these API calls to get response from 2-3 third party applications. The backend server proxies these requests to their respective application.

1. Is it a good idea to aggregate the API calls on the front-end itself or is it better to use the backend to proxy the requests?
2. What is the best way to Aggregate these API calls?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I prefer aggregating APIs/data on the backend. You can design multiple APIs tailored for your clients which only aggregate data from other more generic APIs (e.g. from multiple microservices), or just query data from code and aggregate it if the same service owns all the data. For our project, we created a separate "edge" service for it. Netflix uses this technique to reduce the chattiness of APIs, e.g. on mobile devices. There are many pros:

- You only pay network latency once as viewed from the client. (Intra-service communication should be faster within a same region/cluster)
- Cleaner/less client code.
- Your client developers will love you for it.

Cons (for the backend devs):

- If UI/flow changes, the API may need to change too, but refactoring the client code will be easier with just one API.
- A bit more backend code

More details here: https://netflixtechblog.com/optimizing-the-netflix-api-5c9ac715cf19.

[image]

VS

[image]

Comment: Hey @david 
Thanks for your response. This surely answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

To Aggregate the API calls use `Promise.all()`, it will take an iterable of promises as an input, and returns a single Promise that resolves to an array of the results.

For more, check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: Hey @Yash, Thanks!.